# Statistical significance test for averages of correlation coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, fisher-transform

My setting looks like that I have several subjects $i$ (let's say 5) and for each subject I measure the lists/vectors $A_i$, $B_i$, $C_i$ and $D_i$. Then, for each subject $i$, I calculate the correlation between $A_i$ and $B_i$ (let me call this correlation $AB_i$) as well as between $C_i$ and $D_i$ ($CD_i$). Now, I have for each subject $i$ one correlation coefficient $AB$ and $CD$. Thus, for e.g., five subjects, I have five $AB_i$ correlation coefficients such as $AB'=[AB_1=-0.1, AB_2=0.2, AB_3=0.25, AB_4=0.3, AB_5=0.2]$ and five $CD_i$ coefficients such as $CD'=[CD_1 = 0.8, CD_2=0.8, CD_3=0.75, CD_4=0.9, CD_5=0.7]$.

Now, I want to test the null hypothesis that the correlation coefficients $AB'$ are similar to $CD'$. So basically, whether the mean of $AB'$ is the same as the mean of $CD'$.

Note that $A_i$, $B_i$, $C_i$ and $D_i$ are not repeated measures and focus on different things. Actually, $A_i$ and $C_i$ as well as $B_i$ and $D_i$ correspond to the same variable being measured, but for different sub-groups of my subjects. So, a subject can correspond to a specific event where I can distinguish between sub-groups. E.g., suppose that you study five different school classes (subjects) and for each class you distinguish between males and females (sub-groups). Then you measure two variables (vectors) for both males ($A_i$, $B_i$) and females ($C_i$, $D_i$). Now, I want to know whether $A_i$ correlates similarly to $B_i$ as $C_i$ correlates to $D_i$ across all subjects (school classes).

I know how to calculate a statistical significance test regarding the differences between single correlation coefficients for individual subjects. There are several approaches available; one is to do a Fisher z transformation and then determine the z statistic with known standard deviation. However, how can I do this across subjects (for the mean) in one step?

Normally, I would just pick a t-test. However, the issue I see here is that the correlation coefficients are not normally distributed which is why we could again work with the Fisher transformation somehow. I am unsure how though.

Maybe average the transformed correlations and then conduct a z-test?

I have studied some similar questions withouth finding any answer to this problem. Hope someone has an idea of how to approach this.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "both correlation coefficients are equal across subjects"? You seem to have twice as many computed correlation coefficients as subjects. It's hard to make sense of "both" in that case.

Comment: Suppose we have 10 subjects. For each subject I measure a vector A,B,C and D. For each subject I calculate the correlation coefficient between A and B as well as B and C leading to the coefficients AB and CD. Now, for each subject, I can do a statistical significance test whether both independent coefficients are equal (e.g., with the Fisher test). However, I want to do this across subjects.

Comment: That helps, but I'm still totally lost concerning what you mean by a test "across subjects," because I can think of many distinctly different things this might mean.  What is your null hypothesis?  What is the alternative?

Comment: My null hypothesis is that the correlations between AB and CD are equal. I calculate AB and CD multiple times for multiple subjects. So my vectors for let's say 5 subjects might look like $AB=[0.3,0.2,0.25,-0.1]$ and $CD=[0.7,0.8,0.8,0.75]$.

Comment: I think I might understand your intention but--please excuse me for this--I am worried that I might be totally misunderstanding, because I expected both $AB$ and $CD$ to have five components each, one for each subject, and since you display them with only four components it leaves me thinking I haven't any clue what you're writing about. I'm also uncertain what a "correlation between $AB$ and $CD$" would be. Could that possibly be the correlation coefficient of these two vectors? (If so, then there's only one such correlation, so why do you use the plural?)

Comment: Damn, it is late, sorry. There should be 5 elements in the vectors (can't edit it now). The elements of the vectors are correlation coefficients though that are already calculated for some other vectors. So basically I have vectors of correlation coefficients and I want to test the null that those are similar.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me. I get it now. When you get a chance, please edit your post to include these clarifications so that other readers will understand without having to read through the comments. (In the meantime, +1 to the question.)

Comment: I have edited the post and hope it is clearer now. If you have an idea how to approach this, please let me know :)

Comment: If you have the same subjects in each set of tests, perhaps the paired differences between the $AB_i$ and $CD_i$ would be better behaved for significance testing than the correlation coefficients themselves. Null hypothesis would then be that mean($AB_i - CD_i$) = 0, and you don't throw away information about the individuals.

Comment: Working with correlation coefficients is warranted here for several reasons. So suppose that $AB'$ and $CD'$ should be worked with. But what do you mean with "the same subjects in each set of tests"?

Comment: By "the same subjects in each set of tests" I'm asking if this is a repeated-measures type of design, so that examination of paired differences between the components of the vectors $AB$ and $CD$ could be done.

Comment: No, different subjects.

Comment: I'm confused.  The question says, "for each subject I measure the lists/vectors $A_i, B_i, C_i$ and $D_i$." That seems to suggest a repeated measures design.  Could you clarify? Perhaps a different notation would help?

Comment: To be precise, my setting is a bit more complex, but I wanted to simplify it. Anyhow, $A_i, B_i, C_i$ and $D_i$ are not repeated measures. I will elaborate on it in my question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  If I'm understanding you correctly, then an independent samples t-test would be more appropriate.  I've updated my answer, and also added various additional clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, transform each correlation ($AB_i$ and $CD_i$) using the Fisher $r-to-z'$ transform:
$f(r)=\frac12 ln \frac{1+r}{1-r}$.
  Then, perform an independent samples t-test to test the null hypothesis of  $\mu_{f(AB)}=\mu_{f(CD)}$.

**Rationale:** You're right that approximate normality is important here.  With only a small number of subjects, you can't count on the central limit theorem to address the (often) non-normal sampling distribution of *r*.  The sampling distribution of *r* will only be approximately normal when $\rho$ is close to 0 or when *n* is very large (here, I refer to the *n* used to compute the correlation, not the *n* indexed by *i* in your question).  Based on the examples in your question, I'm guessing *n* is modest, and if you already knew the $\rho$'s, there'd be no point in asking your question. Bottom line: the Fisher $r-to-z'$ will probably help here.

It sounds like you're comparing independent samples, especially based on this part of your description:

> $A_i$ and $C_i$ as well as $B_i$ and $D_i$ correspond to the same variable being measured, but for different sub-groups of my subjects.

So, it makes sense to use an independent samples t-test.

Comment: From late entries in the comment thread above, this might not be a paired situation. Will your approach also work if these are unpaired comparisons?

Comment: Thanks! I have extended my original post to adhere to the comments by @EdM.

Comment: Thank you, that answer confirm my personal intuition. One final thing though: Instead of a t-test, could I also use a z-test here as the Fisher transformation has known variance?

Comment: Good point. I suppose you could do a z-test if you analytically solve for the variance of $mean(f(AB))-mean(f(CD))$.

Comment: What would the degrees of freedom be in the independent samples $t$-test?